# Discord Bot: cannot create POST request for create a message

Tags: c++, api, sockets

i have a problem while i am implementing discord bot in C/C++.
My problem is when i when i want to create message in other way create POST request to create message with my BOT i do not recieve any answer whether the request was completed or not.
When i create GET request with specifics which is necessary due to discord documentary everything is good and i recieve what i want.
My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>``
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <signal.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <openssl/err.h> /* errors */

#include <openssl/ssl.h> /* core library */
#include <thread> 

#define BuffSize 8096

using namespace std;
    
SSL *ssl;
int sock;
    
int RecvPacket()
{
    int len=100;
    char buf[1000000];
    do {
        len=SSL_read(ssl, buf, 100);
        buf[len]=0;
        printf("%s\n",buf);
//        fprintf(fp, "%s",buf);
    } while (len > 0);
    if (len < 0) {
        int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, len);
    if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
            return 0;
        if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
            return 0;
        if (err == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN || err == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL || err == SSL_ERROR_SSL)
            return -1;
    }
}
    
int SendPacket(const char *buf)
{
    int len = SSL_write(ssl, buf, strlen(buf));
    if (len < 0) {
        int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, len);
        switch (err) {
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            return 0;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            return 0;
        case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
        case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
        case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
        default:
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
    
void log_ssl()
{
    int err;
    while (err = ERR_get_error()) {
        char *str = ERR_error_string(err, 0);
        if (!str)
            return;
        printf(str);
        printf("\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    struct sockaddr_in socket_address_IPv4;
    struct hostent *hos;
    int socket_invoke;
      string messageId;
      string username;
      char content[1024];
      string messageBodyString;
    char messageBody[BuffSize];
    char* response_2;
    char *token=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[1]));
    char *url_uncompleted=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) *300);
    char *ip=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) *100);
    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    int i=0;
    strcpy(url_uncompleted,"www.discord.com:443");
    char *url = strtok(url_uncompleted, ":");
    strcpy(token,argv[1]);
    
   
    socket_invoke = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(socket < 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Unsuccessfull creation of seocket\n");

    }
    memset(&socket_address_IPv4,0,sizeof(socket_address_IPv4));
    socket_address_IPv4.sin_family=AF_INET;
    
    hos=gethostbyname(url);
    if(!hos){   
        printf("chyba pri gethostbyname\n");
        close(socket_invoke);
        exit(10);
        
    }

    
    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) hos->h_addr_list;

    for(int i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) 
    {
        //Return the first one;
        strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
        break;
    }
    printf("IP adresa je: %s\n",ip);
    socket_address_IPv4.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
    socket_address_IPv4.sin_port=htons(443);
    
    
    
    if(connect(socket_invoke,(struct sockaddr*)&socket_address_IPv4,sizeof(socket_address_IPv4)) <0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"connection failed\n");
        free(token);
        free(url_uncompleted);
        free(ip);
        close(socket_invoke);

    }
    SSL_library_init();
    SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    const SSL_METHOD *meth = TLSv1_2_client_method();
    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new (meth);
    ssl = SSL_new (ctx);
    if (!ssl) {
        printf("Error creating SSL.\n");
        log_ssl();
        return -1;
    }
    sock = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, socket_invoke);
    int err = SSL_connect(ssl);
    if (err <= 0) {
        printf("Error creating SSL connection.  err=%x\n", err);
        log_ssl();
        fflush(stdout);
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher (ssl));
    
    snprintf(messageBody, 1024, "{\"content\":\"hi\",\n\"tts\": false}");
        sprintf(content,
          "POST https://discord.com/api/v6/channels/760577856702644327/messages HTTP/1.1\r\nauthorization: Bot %s\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 1024\r\nhost: %s\r\n%s\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n",token,"discord.com",messageBody);
          printf("%s\n",content);
    SendPacket(content);
    RecvPacket();
    

    
        
        
        printf("som tu\n");
        free(token);
        free(url_uncompleted);
        free(ip);
        close(socket_invoke);

        return 0;

  }
```

thank you for all advices

Comment: There's no C/C++ programming language. Your code is clearly c++.

Comment: `char buf[1000000];` don't stress your stack against the limits, ratther use a `std::vector<char> buf(1000000);`  to allocate enough space dynamically. You can pass the `data()` pointer to interact with plain C APIs.

Comment: The request you send is invalid in many things: You should use the path and not the full URL in the request line, you try to send the messageBody  inside the header (before the `Connection` header),  you claim that the size of the message body is 1024 even if it clearly is not (1024 is the size of the buffer which contains the body, but not the body itself). And you have a messed up indentation which makes reading your code unessesary hard.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what does it mean ? how should it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have (slightly reformatted and with added line numbers for better reading):

```
 1   sprintf(content,
 2     "POST https://discord.com/api/v6/channels/760577856702644327/messages HTTP/1.1\r\n"
 3     "authorization: Bot %s\r\n"
 4     "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
 5     "Content-Length: 1024\r\nhost: %s\r\n"
 6     "%s\r\n"
 7     "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n",
 8     token,"discord.com",messageBody);
```

The are several problems with this:

- In the request line you should only have the path but not the full URL, i.e. only `/api/v6/channels/760577856702644327/messages`. Some servers might accept the full URL, others don't.
- The `messageBody` (line 8) is inserted into the HTTP header in line 6 instead of adding add after the HTTP header, i.e. after the final `\r\n\r\n`.
- In line 5 you give a `Content-Length` of 1024. But this is not the actual length of the contents of the message, it is instead the size of the buffer `messageBody`. The actual content is much smaller and should be determined with `strlen(messageBody)`.

Apart from that you claim to support HTTP persistent connection both by using `Connection: keep-alive` and by using `HTTP/1.1` (which defaults to keep-alive, i.e. the header wasn't even needed). But you don't actually support it. Instead you expect the server to close the connection after the request which is the opposite of keep-alive. To fix this you better remove the `Connection` header and switch to `HTTP/1.0`. This also simplifies other things, like no need to implement support for chunked transfer encoding (which you also don't have).

In general, HTTP is more complex than it looks and it would be better to either use an existing library or study and fully understand the actual HTTP standard before starting to implement it.